# php - Self function is called without defining it

Tags: php, laravel

I came across a function, which is being called without defining it anywhere.
No error is shown from intelphense as well.
function I am referring to in the below code is
`self::whereIdenityNumber($identityNumber)->exists();`

```
public static function generateUniqueIdentityNumber()
{
    $identityNumber = strtoupper(Str::random(10));
    while (true) {
        $isExist = self::whereIdenityNumber($identityNumber)->exists();
        if ($isExist) {
            self::generateUniqueIdenityNumber();
        }
        break;
    }

    return $identityNumber;
}
```

There is no problem with the function, just wanted to know how it works.

note:
there is a comment like below in docblock comments. Can this be treated as defining the function?

```
* @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\Models\IdentityUser whereIdentityNumber($value)
```

Answer (score 0):

That static method seems to be defined at \App\Models\IdentityUser

You must have something like:

```
Class IdentityUser extends Model{

  public static whereIdentityNumber($query){
   
   ...
  
  }


}
```